# REGEX Get last 6 digits from string

Tags: regex

I am trying to get the last 6 digits from the strings that look like this

`1234-56789` -- last 6 digits would be `456789`

`12345/6789` -- last 6 digits would be `456789`

`1234567-89` -- last 6 digits would be `456789`

`123-456789` -- last 6 digits would be `456789`

This `\d.{6}+$` regex gives me the numbers with characters `-` and `/`.

Output for `1234-56789` is `4-56789`. So how can i get `456789` without characters `-` and `/`?

Best regards

Comment: Only regex wanted?

Comment: If you're on Unix you could do something like `echo '1234-56789' | sed -E 's,[^0-9],,g' | tail -c7`

Comment: You can do what you want in two steps: 1. remove the problematic characters (replace with empty string) 2. match with `\d{6}$` (the last 6 digits).

Comment: The problem is that i can not do it in two steps. I am working in Aurea CRM and the regex needs to be used in Worklow (not sure that anybody knows about Aurea CRM but that is my issue). If there is a possibility with one line of regex it would be greate, if not i have to figure another way.

Comment: Do you have any more restrictions on the input? Will it always have such a character? Is it possible an input will be `123456k789` or `123456--789`?

Comment: I am not sure that is possible to have, like "*joined seperated matches*" with only regex. The best you could have is the last group of digits I guess, or a group of six digits with the unwanted characters in it (as you did).

Comment: no, just characters "-" or "/" like i described in post

Comment: well i also thought that it is not possible with one line in regex, i had to ask

Comment: If you can you multiple groups as a result, you can try `(\d{1})\D(\d{5})|(\d{2})\D(\d{4})|...` and the combination of all groups (`\1\2\3\4...`) will be the number you want.

Comment: The long version: `(?:(\d{6})|(\d{1})\D(\d{5})|(\d{2})\D(\d{4})|(\d{3})\D(\d{3})|(\d{4})\D(\d{2})|(\d{5})\D(\d{1})|(\d{6})\D)$` https://regex101.com/r/vZ0EaO/1

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @oram. First you can find the problamatic charcater with `\D`, replace with `"" (empty string)` and then get the final string with `\d{6}$`.

Answer (score 0):

- One problem with this is that not all regex engines are created
  equal. So if Python supports it, Java may not.
- Another is that I am unaware of being able to exclude a group of
  characters from a subgroup and combine the results  (although there could be brute force solutions that result in long regexes).

But keeping with the keep it simple principle, here is a solution in Java that could be adapted to other languages

```java
      String[] data =
            { "1234-56789", "12345/6789", "1234567-89", "123-456789", "12-223"
            };
      for (String s : data) {
         String temp = s.replaceAll("[/-]", "");
         String lastSix = "String too short";
         if (temp.length() >= 6) {
            lastSix = temp.substring(temp.length() - 6, temp.length());
         }
         System.out.println(lastSix);
      }
```